# JavaFX label wrapped within HBox within ScrollPane not working

Tags: javafx-2

I try to build chat using `ScrollPane` for scrolling and `VBox` for the view (`scroll.setContent(vbox);`). Each message create new `HBox` and `Label` in it.
The label contain the text and declared `text.setWrapText(true);`

When there is enough space without scrolling its work fine:

[image: Wrapping work]

But when the messages height greater then the `VHox` height (view of the `ScrollPane`) the wrapping not working:

[image: Wrapping not working]

**EDIT:** relevant code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ChatExample extends Application
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception
    {
        ScrollPane scroll = new ScrollPane();
        scroll.setFitToHeight(true);
        scroll.setPrefSize(300, 300);
        VBox chat = new VBox();
        chat.setSpacing(10);
        scroll.setContent(chat);

        chat.getChildren().add(addMessage("This is a wrapped message, This is a wrapped message"));
        chat.getChildren().add(addMessage("This is a wrapped message, This is a wrapped message"));
        chat.getChildren().add(addMessage("This is a wrapped message, This is a wrapped message"));
        chat.getChildren().add(addMessage("This is a wrapped message, This is a wrapped message"));

        final Scene scene = new Scene(scroll, 300, 300);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public HBox addMessage(String message)
    {
        HBox hbox = new HBox();
        Label label = new Label(message);
        label.setWrapText(true);
        label.setMaxWidth(50);

        hbox.getChildren().add(label);
        return hbox;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete & Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (aka MCVE).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @sillyfly on writing small example I figured out what case this situation.

`scroll.setFitToHeight(true);` made this issue, so I removed it

Comment: As far as I understand fitToHeight was used to make messages appear from the bottom to the top. Could you please show that small example to understand what the cause of  this problem is and if there are any workarounds, because I need this fitToHeight functionality.